# Splunk java sdk return XML

Tags: splunk

I am making a REST call to Splunk and need to now how I get the full XML from ResultsReaderXml

```
InputStream results = jobSavedSearch.getResults();
ResultsReaderXml resultsReader = new ResultsReaderXml(results);
```

I can push the reader to a hash and print, but I want the full XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results reader is meant to tokenize the XML into key value pairs. If you want the raw XML, just pull the data directly from the stream. For example:

```
InputStream results = jobSavedSearch.getResults();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(results, "UTF8");
```

Now you can read directly from the stream reader -- its all just a stream of text at this point.